# Dictionary - replace keys' spaces with _, keep values the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries whose keys contain spaces.

```
input = [{'books author': 'bob', 'book title': 'three wolves'},{'books author': 'tim', 'book title': 'three apples'}]
```

How would I go about iterating over the said list of dictionaries, and replacing the keys' that contain spaces, with underscores, with output being

```
output = [{'books_author': 'bob', 'book_title': 'three wolves'},{'books_author': 'tim', 'book_title': 'three apples'}]
```

Note, the actual dictionaries can contain a few hundred keys, and a list will consist of thousands of `dict`s.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempts?

Comment: I understand where you're coming from .  Basically I tried iterating over the list of dicts, using .items() in py 3, then generating brand new dictionaries...  which i figured is probably the least efficient way of doing it:
x = [{'books author': 'bob', 'book title': 'three wolves'},{'books author': 'tim', 'book title': 'three apples'}]


import copy
y = []
for oned in x:
    for key,value in oned.items():
        print(key,value)
        oned[key] = key.replace(" ","_")
        print(key)
    print(oned)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `dict`-comprehension within a `list`-comprehension, and use `str.replace` for the changing of  to `_`:

```
in_list = [{'books author': 'bob', 'book title': 'three wolves'},{'books author': 'tim', 'book title': 'three apples'}]

out_list = [{k.replace(' ', '_') : v for k, v in d.items()} for d in in_list]

print(out_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'books_author': 'bob', 'book_title': 'three wolves'}, {'books_author': 'tim', 'book_title': 'three apples'}]
```

Comment: That was fast! I couldn't get it work on time haha, very good answer. Pls 1

Comment: @DamiánRafaelLattenero This always happens to me :P !

Comment: It's your turn to shine so hahaha, I didn't know that I had to put .items(), so I got only the first value changed, so I lost a few minutes figuring why

Comment: Thanks again MrGeek

Answer (score 2):

A mix of list comprehension a dict comprehension could work:

```
res = [{(k.replace(" ", "_")):v for (k,v) in dct.items()} for dct in inp]
```